# Chart with X and Y axis as column 1 and column 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

Refer to the pic below:

[image]

Using the code below I am getting the 1st graph but what I need is the second graph. Please let me know where I am wrong

```
import openpyxl

xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook("chart.xlsx")
sheet = xfile["Chart"]
c = openpyxl.chart.LineChart()

c.title = "Graph"
c.style = 1

c.y_axis.title = 'Time'
c.x_axis.title = 'WF'

data = openpyxl.chart.Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=sheet.max_row)
c.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)

sheet.add_chart(c, "C1")
xfile.save("chart.xlsx")
```

Comment: Some details to add so I can correct my answer? I suppose it is incorrect if you ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not fully clear.
I suppose your problem is just regarding the X axis and not about the styling of the chart.

To obtain the "same" chart you have to set the labels of the X axis selecting those values  from the first column.

```py
    import openpyxl

    chart_directory = "chart.xlsx"

    xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook(chart_directory)
    sheet = xfile["Chart"]
    c = openpyxl.chart.LineChart()

    c.title = "Graph"
    c.style = 2

    c.y_axis.title = 'Time'
    c.x_axis.title = 'WF'

    #Select the lables to set
    labels = openpyxl.chart.Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=sheet.max_row, max_col=1)
    #Select the values to set
    data = openpyxl.chart.Reference(sheet, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=sheet.max_row)

    #Set the values
    c.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
    #Set the labels
    c.set_categories(labels)

    sheet.add_chart(c, "C1")
    xfile.save(chart_directory)
```

In this sample code you can see that I select the labels as column 1 from the row 2 until the last row.
After that you can select the values to print as column 2 from the row 1 (so it keeps the legend name of the series) until the last row.

You have to set the data in the chart, and after that the labels.